# BS5 accordion disappear every click on header

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I'm using BS5 accordion. Comparing to the doc but don't see any difference. Everytime I click header - it's gone.

```html
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="collapseMain">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="collapse1">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse1">head1</button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapse1" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="collapse1" data-bs-parent="#collapseMain">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        xxx</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- accordion-item -->
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="collapse2">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse2">head2</button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapse2" class="accordion-collapse collapse " aria-labelledby="collapse2" data-bs-parent="#collapseMain">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        xxx</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- accordion-item -->
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="collapse3">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse3">head3</button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapse3" class="accordion-collapse collapse " aria-labelledby="collapse3" data-bs-parent="#collapseMain">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        xxx</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- accordion-item -->
</div>
<!-- accordion accordion-flush -->
```

Answer (score 0):

it's because you are using id="collapse1",
bootstrap5 supports id="heading1"

```
<h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading1">
```

Comment: yes it does try doing this ...in bootstrap4 they defined the id="collapse1" to collapse the div but they have changed it in bootstrap5 ...now they use id="heading1"

Comment: I got it now. Because I have duplicate id both in `.accordion-header` and `.accordion-collapse`.

Comment: exactly it is it